# Where should I place my reaction code in Per-Pixel Collision Detection?

Tags: xna, collision-detection

I have this collision detection code:

```
public bool PerPixelCollision(Player player, Game1 dog)
{
    Matrix atob = player.Transform * Matrix.Invert(dog.Transform);

    Vector2 stepX = Vector2.TransformNormal(Vector2.UnitX, atob);
    Vector2 stepY = Vector2.TransformNormal(Vector2.UnitY, atob);

    Vector2 iBPos = Vector2.Transform(Vector2.Zero, atob);

    for(int deltax = 0; deltax < player.playerTexture.Width; deltax++)
    {
        Vector2 bpos = iBPos;
        for (int deltay = 0; deltay < player.playerTexture.Height; deltay++)
        {
            int bx = (int)bpos.X;
            int by = (int)bpos.Y;

            if (bx >= 0 && bx < dog.dogTexture.Width && by >= 0 && by < dog.dogTexture.Height)
            {
                if (player.TextureData[deltax + deltay * player.playerTexture.Width].A > 150 && dog.TextureData[bx + by * dog.Texture.Width].A > 150)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            bpos += stepY;
        }
        iBPos += stepX;
    }
    return false;
}
```

What I want to know is where to put in the code where something happens. For example, I want to put in `player.playerPosition.X -= 200` just as a test, but I don't know where to put it. I tried putting it under the `return true` and above it, but under it, it said unreachable code, and above it nothing happened. I also tried putting it by                `bpos += stepY;` but that didn't work either. Where do I put the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to learn how to use the debugger. I found a dubugger tutorial for XNA in parts [One](http://xnaessentials.com/archive/2009/05/06/advanced-debugging-tutorial-part-one.aspx) and [Two](http://xnaessentials.com/archive/2009/07/27/advanced-debugging-part-two.aspx). It says advanced, but it starts out pretty basic with breakpoints and ramps up from there.

If you want to test your collision code, you can set a break point at the top and step through it, or you can set breakpoints at the return case you want to look at. I recommend starting with setting the breakpoint at the top and stepping though your code. I think you're at a pretty beginner level, and it would be very valuable to see how your code is actually executed. Once you look at this enough I think you'll be able to figure out why putting code after a return statement will never be reached.

Comment: I put the                         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This is my debug message."); in every spot possible and put a breakpoint at the top. Nothing wrote out.

Comment: Then function isn't getting called. Or you're not running in debug mode.